# pandas get/differentiate latest store location and statuses for customers who made a switch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a task to differentiate between customers who are purchasing simultaneously with two different stores and those who have made a complete switch along the way.

the data I have is given below

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'Id': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'B'}, 'Store': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A001', 4: 'C001', 5: 'C001', 6: 'C001', 7: 'C001', 8: 'A001', 9: 'A001', 10: 'B001', 11: 'B001', 12: 'B001'}, 'Date': {0: '1-Dec-21', 1: '1-Jan-22', 2: '1-Feb-22', 3: '1-Mar-22', 4: '1-Dec-21', 5: '1-Jan-22', 6: '1-Feb-22', 7: '1-Mar-22', 8: '1-Dec-21', 9: '1-Jan-22', 10: '1-Jan-22', 11: '1-Feb-22', 12: '1-Mar-22'}, 'Purchases': {0: 5000, 1: 60000, 2: 4897, 3: 8752, 4: 4000, 5: 3000, 6: 2000, 7: 1000, 8: 7500, 9: 8500, 10: 1250, 11: 10000, 12: 11000}, 'Orders': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 8, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 15, 9: 16, 10: 2, 11: 11, 12: 10}, 'R_Status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'No', 4: 'No', 5: 'No', 6: 'No', 7: 'No', 8: 'No', 9: 'No', 10: 'Yes', 11: 'Yes', 12: 'Yes'}})
```

Shape of data

```
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+
| Id | Store |   Date   | Purchases | Orders | R_Status |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+
| A  | A001  | 1-Dec-21 |      5000 |     11 | No       |
| A  | A001  | 1-Jan-22 |     60000 |     12 | No       |
| A  | A001  | 1-Feb-22 |      4897 |      8 | No       |
| A  | A001  | 1-Mar-22 |      8752 |      5 | No       |
| A  | C001  | 1-Dec-21 |      4000 |      2 | No       |
| A  | C001  | 1-Jan-22 |      3000 |      3 | No       |
| A  | C001  | 1-Feb-22 |      2000 |      1 | No       |
| A  | C001  | 1-Mar-22 |      1000 |      1 | No       |
| B  | A001  | 1-Dec-21 |      7500 |     15 | No       |
| B  | A001  | 1-Jan-22 |      8500 |     16 | No       |
| B  | B001  | 1-Jan-22 |      1250 |      2 | Yes      |
| B  | B001  | 1-Feb-22 |     10000 |     11 | Yes      |
| B  | B001  | 1-Mar-22 |     11000 |     10 | Yes      |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

My desired output looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'Id': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'B'}, 'Store': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A001', 4: 'C001', 5: 'C001', 6: 'C001', 7: 'C001', 8: 'A001', 9: 'A001', 10: 'B001', 11: 'B001', 12: 'B001'}, 'Date': {0: '1-Dec-21', 1: '1-Jan-22', 2: '1-Feb-22', 3: '1-Mar-22', 4: '1-Dec-21', 5: '1-Jan-22', 6: '1-Feb-22', 7: '1-Mar-22', 8: '1-Dec-21', 9: '1-Jan-22', 10: '1-Jan-22', 11: '1-Feb-22', 12: '1-Mar-22'}, 'Purchases': {0: 5000, 1: 60000, 2: 4897, 3: 8752, 4: 4000, 5: 3000, 6: 2000, 7: 1000, 8: 7500, 9: 8500, 10: 1250, 11: 10000, 12: 11000}, 'Orders': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 8, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 15, 9: 16, 10: 2, 11: 11, 12: 10}, 'Switch_flag': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1}, 'Previous_Store': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A001', 4: 'C001', 5: 'C001', 6: 'C001', 7: 'C001', 8: 'A001', 9: 'A001', 10: 'A001', 11: 'A001', 12: 'A001'}, 'Updated_store': {0: 'A001', 1: 'A001', 2: 'A001', 3: 'A001', 4: 'C001', 5: 'C001', 6: 'C001', 7: 'C001', 8: 'B001', 9: 'B001', 10: 'B001', 11: 'B001', 12: 'B001'}, 'Updated R_status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'No', 4: 'No', 5: 'No', 6: 'No', 7: 'No', 8: 'Yes', 9: 'Yes', 10: 'Yes', 11: 'Yes', 12: 'Yes'}})
```

Desired output

```
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
| Id | Store |   Date   | Purchases | Orders | Switch_flag | Previous_Store | Updated_store | Updated R_status |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
| A  | A001  | 1-Dec-21 |      5000 |     11 |           0 | A001           | A001          | No               |
| A  | A001  | 1-Jan-22 |     60000 |     12 |           0 | A001           | A001          | No               |
| A  | A001  | 1-Feb-22 |      4897 |      8 |           0 | A001           | A001          | No               |
| A  | A001  | 1-Mar-22 |      8752 |      5 |           0 | A001           | A001          | No               |
| A  | C001  | 1-Dec-21 |      4000 |      2 |           0 | C001           | C001          | No               |
| A  | C001  | 1-Jan-22 |      3000 |      3 |           0 | C001           | C001          | No               |
| A  | C001  | 1-Feb-22 |      2000 |      1 |           0 | C001           | C001          | No               |
| A  | C001  | 1-Mar-22 |      1000 |      1 |           0 | C001           | C001          | No               |
| B  | A001  | 1-Dec-21 |      7500 |     15 |           1 | A001           | B001          | Yes              |
| B  | A001  | 1-Jan-22 |      8500 |     16 |           1 | A001           | B001          | Yes              |
| B  | B001  | 1-Jan-22 |      1250 |      2 |           1 | A001           | B001          | Yes              |
| B  | B001  | 1-Feb-22 |     10000 |     11 |           1 | A001           | B001          | Yes              |
| B  | B001  | 1-Mar-22 |     11000 |     10 |           1 | A001           | B001          | Yes              |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
```

So, I want to add few fields in front of the customers to identify whether customer made a switch or not and update the columns with new stores so that I can work with them for aggregation purposes.

It's also possible that resultant output has only aggregated values for customer `B` i.e. it has two records for Jan and I can group them into one.

Eventual goal is to have total purchases against each customer so my final output will be like this

```
{'Id': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'},
 'Store': {0: 'A001', 1: 'C001', 2: 'B001'},
 'Total Purchases': {0: 78649, 1: 10000, 2: 38250},
 'Orders': {0: 36, 1: 7, 2: 54},
 'R_Status': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'Yes'}}
```

```
+----+-------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| Id | Store | Total Purchases | Orders | R_Status |
+----+-------+-----------------+--------+----------+
| A  | A001  |           78649 |     36 | No       |
| A  | C001  |           10000 |      7 | No       |
| B  | B001  |           38250 |     54 | Yes      |
+----+-------+-----------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: It feel that the problem is ill-defined. Imagine 3 stores visited by customer A. After some time there is a switch from uniquely store1 to store2 **and** store3, how do you define the updated_store now?

Comment: @mozway, good point but within current data in hand customers are either allowed to purchase simultaneously with only two stores or make a complete shift.

Comment: @mozway, Updated my question to include final output